# Change database in sql connection with mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I would like to make sql/sp calls to multiple databases on the same server. I am using mssql and don't see the "changeUser" option that mysql provides. Do I have to close and reconnect every time I wish to change databases? Seems like this would be a commonly desired behaviour.

Simply having an sql connection for each database is not doable, as the error "Global connection already exists." will occur.

Comment: See TSQL's `USE database_name` statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft This looks like it would work for sql statements, which was my prompt but what if using stored procedures?

Comment: It changes the session's current database.  Subsequent statements will be executed in the context of the new database.  Although I'm not sure why you would have a single "gloal connection" in any server-side programming environment.

Comment: I see. Are you suggesting a connection pool?

Comment: A connection pool is the standard approach.  You can't use a single connection concurrently for multiple requests, and opening a new physical connection for each request is too expensive.